# SQL possible to display (only display) a non-date string in a date column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wondered if its possible to show a "-" whenever there is no date **in a date column**?

So one tuple might be {Dave, 13th July 2011}, whereas another could be {John,-}

EDIT: Thanks to the person below who suggested this:

```
SELECT `ID`, COALESCE(CAST(`Graduation Date` AS CHAR), '-') FROM <table>
```

It worked!

Answer (score 2):

Use `COALESCE`?

```
SELECT name, COALESCE(date, '-')
FROM table
```

EDIT: Don't see how it is possible that it doesn't work. Example:

```
SELECT COALESCE('2011-01-01', '-') //returns '2011-01-01'
SELECT COALESCE('', '-') //returns ''
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, '-') //returns '-'
```

Try them 3 statements and you will see what is returned.

EDIT2:

```
SELECT name, IF(COALESCE(date, '-') = '', '-', date)
FROM table
```

Comment: If it doesn't work then date is not null. Also, "didn't appear to work" doesn't give much info to help you with. Maybe provide the SQL query you are using and/or the results you get.

Comment: It doesnt work.

SELECT `ID`,COALESCE(`Graduation Date`,'-') FROM <Table>

I have also checked whether they are blank strings and they're definitely not.

I've used Describe Table and `Graduation Date` is of type DATETIME and Null is allowed.

Comment: @James: verify that your `Graduation Date` column in the database does actually contain NULL values, and not 0000-00-00

Comment: Maybe MySQL is confused about the type - so a CAST(date AS CHAR) would help:  `SELECT Name, COALESCE(CAST(Date AS CHAR), '-') FROM Table`?

Comment: @anothershrubery, i'm interacting with the DB via HTML and it's returning a blank string. However, i believe this is actually a NULL just being displayed by the HTML using a blank string.

Comment: The only other way to do it is to check for blank strings as well. See edit #2 above. Or just do what Jonathan says, if that works...

Answer (score 1):

If your date column contains some special dates that you would like to treat in the same way as NULLs (for example, `0000-00-00`), you could try this method:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(yourdatecolumn, '0000-00-00'), '-')
```

That is essentially just a shorter way of writing this:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN yourdatecolumn IS NULL OR yourdatecolumn = '0000-00-00' THEN '-'
         ELSE yourdatecolumn
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, IF(GRADUATIONDATE IS NULL, '-', GRADUATIONDATE) FROM TABLE

or 

SELECT ID, IFNULL(GRADUATIONDATE,'-') FROM TABLE
```

Comment: This seemed to just blank them all out

Comment: Like anothershrubery, I will need the results and query to help further.

Comment: I ran what you said, swapped Username for one of our other columns, swapped Date for the name of the date field and it showed the identifiers, with no dates whatsoever (there are some in the data, approximately 90% have valid dates, 10% i wish to enter '-')